# Retrieve categories of a WooCommerce product in hierachical order

Tags: plugins

I'm using this code and getting only a forward slash for results.  I'm trying to print the parent category of a WooCommerce product.

```
$prod_cat = get_category_parents($product->id);
echo $prod_cat;
```

Any idea how to modify it so it prints the parent categories name?

Comment: what is `$product`? [`get_category_parents`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents) expects a category ID.

Answer (score 1):

The [`get_category_parents`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents) is a function that retrieve the parent categories passing as argument a **category id**.

So, if you have a product and you want to retrieve a list of attached categories to it, the right function is `get_the_terms`.That function return all the categories objects, without order, and so you can take the first of these categories and call `get_category_parents`.

Assuming the `$product` variable contain a post object, you can use

```
$cats = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );
echo $cats ? get_category_parents( array_shift($cats)->term_id ) : '';
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back G.M. - I tried your code but only got a / on the page when I view it.  The above code from ialocin works though and it's exactly what I need.  I really appreciate the response though.  Thank you very much!

Comment: worked for me but with array_pop

Answer (score 1):

Below code should do what you want, it has the benefit of working in `product` and `product category` environments. Besides that it has some options build in, as described under `how to use`.

#### code

```
function wc_origin_trail_ancestor( $link = false, $trail = false ) {

    if (is_product_category()) {
        global $wp_query;
        $q_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $cat_id = $q_obj->term_id;

        $descendant = get_term_by("id", $cat_id, "product_cat");
        $descendant_id = $descendant->term_id;

        $ancestors = get_ancestors($cat_id, 'product_cat');
        $ancestors = array_reverse($ancestors);

        $origin_ancestor = get_term_by("id", $ancestors[0], "product_cat");
        $origin_ancestor_id = $origin_ancestor->term_id;

        $ac = count($ancestors);

    } else if ( is_product() ) {

        $descendant = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
        $descendant = array_reverse($descendant);
        $descendant = $descendant[0];
        $descendant_id = $descendant->term_id;

        $ancestors = array_reverse(get_ancestors($descendant_id, 'product_cat'));
        $ac = count($ancestors);

    }


    $c = 1;
    if( $trail == false ){

        $origin_ancestor_term = get_term_by("id", $ancestors[0], "product_cat");
        $origin_ancestor_link = get_term_link( $origin_ancestor_term->slug, $origin_ancestor_term->taxonomy );

        if($link == true) 
            echo '<a href="'. $origin_ancestor_link .'">';
        echo $origin_ancestor_term->name;
        if($link == true) 
            echo '</a>';

    }else{

        foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
            $ancestor_term = get_term_by("id", $ancestor, "product_cat");
            $ancestor_link = get_term_link( $ancestor_term->slug, $ancestor_term->taxonomy );

            if($c++ == 1) 
                echo '» '; 
            else if($c++ != 1 || $c++ != $ac) 
                echo ' » ';

            if($link == true) 
                echo '<a href="'. $ancestor_link .'">';
            echo  $ancestor_term->name;
            if($link == true) 
                echo '</a>';

        }

        $descendant_term = get_term_by("id", $descendant_id, "product_cat");
        $descendant_link = get_term_link( $descendant_term->slug, $descendant_term->taxonomy );

        echo ' » ';
        if($link == true) 
            echo '<a href="'. $descendant_link .'">';
        echo $descendant->name;
        if($link == true) 
            echo '</a>';

    }

}
```

#### how to use

- just toplevel, origin ancestor; without link
  `wc_origin_trail_ancestor();`
- just toplevel, origin ancestor; with link
  `wc_origin_trail_ancestor(true);`
- ancestor trail; without link
  `wc_origin_trail_ancestor(false,true);`
- ancestor trail; with link
  `wc_origin_trail_ancestor(true,true);`

#### notes

- won't work if a product has multiple main-/toplevel-categories, or at least won't show them all;
- same should be the case for multiple subcategories on the same level;

Comment: Awesome!  This works perfectly for what I need.  I was so far off.

PS. I don't get a link or any text when I use the "just toplevel, origin ancestor; with link
wc_origin_trail_ancestor(true);"

Comment: I spoke too soon :(  

It works fine mostly but on categories where the subcategory was created after the parent category it shows the subcategory name and not the parent.  

When I add a new subcategory (called Grand Piano) to a parent category (called New).  It displays "Grand Piano" instead of "New" even though "New" is the parent. The rest of the categories/subcategories display fine and like they should.  It's only on subcategories with a higher Tag_ID then the parent category.  Is there a fix to this?

Comment: @lankywood: The link is working fine for me, so I'm not sure about that. But I see where the other problem is you are describing, give me a minute or two, I will update the code.