# How can I display *only* the child category of a product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm currently using the following code to try and display the child category of products:-

```
global $post, $product;
$cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
?>

<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<h3 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">by <?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?></h3>
```

This outputs both the parent and child category separated by a comma. Is there an easy way to just display the child category and not the parent category?

Any help or pointers are much appreciated ;)

Comment: See if this helps you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124770/how-to-order-the-get-categories-result

Comment: Thanks @WisdmLabs. I will bookmark that solution too, but I found another late last night which I hadn't had time to add to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I was directed to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896981/display-deepest-child-category-for-current-product-in-woocommerce) – which solved my problem 100%. Here is the solution I used from that post.

```
// get all product cats for the current post
$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' ); 

// wrapper to hide any errors from top level categories or products without category
if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $category ) ) : 

    // loop through each cat
    foreach($categories as $category) :
      // get the children (if any) of the current cat
      $children = get_categories( array ('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'parent' => $category->term_id ));

      if ( count($children) == 0 ) {
          // if no children, then echo the category name.
          echo $category->name;
      }
    endforeach;

endif;
```

Comment: Please add a solution and not just a link to where someone might find a solution. Link only answers is poor quality answers which should be avoided

Comment: Hi @PieterGoosen, sorry, relatively new at posting here. I have now updated my post to have the solution as well as the link.

Comment: Great, thank you. Now, even when the link dies, your answer will still be useful to others as well. +1